# How can I select a specific cell value filtering with the nearest date (in a column) to select a specific row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am very new in Excel and I have to implement this pretty complex task (at least for me it is complex).

I put what I am doing here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sWHbyl-Y-GgSiX7JJ3bJ9_y8DUts-E0e

I will try to explain exactly what I have to do:

For each rows I have to "calculate" the value of the **L** column in this way.

Each cell into the **L** column is "calculated" using the following steps:

- Considers the date into the **H** column of this row.
- Search the nearest date in the past into the **A** column to select a specific row.
- Take the **E** column value of this row and use it to populate the current **L** cell.

So doing a practical example, I want to populate the **L3** cell, I have to do:

- Considers the date into the **H** column of this row: so I obtain the value of the **H3** row that is this date: **16/12/2017**.
- Then, into the whole **A** column I search the nearest date in the past in this column (in this case it is **15/12/2017**), so I select the **row number 4**.
- Take the value of **E4** cell value (**598,05 €**) and write it into my **L3** cell.

How can I do something like this?

Thank you

Comment: I will not download or open any file, can you upload some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `INDEX(...,MATCH())` situation.

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(H3,A:A,1))
```

This will return the value in column E such that the date in column A is the greatest date less than or equal to the value in H3.

---

Note: This assumes the dates in column A are sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(H3,A:E,5,TRUE)
```

This requires the dates in Column A to be sorted.